# camera and map crashes when launched from my custom home screen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, launcher, homescreen

I've created a custom home screen.
This is my code to launch an application when clicked:

```
mainIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(strPackageName);
if(mainIntent!=null)
{
    mainIntent = mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)
                           .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
}
```

Everything works fine except that while launching Camera or Google Maps i get an exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(845): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(845): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.camera/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1536)
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1510)
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2858)
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2964)
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at com.gears42.surelock.ApplicationLauncher.onItemClick(ApplicationLauncher.java:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
E/AndroidRuntime(845):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


E/AndroidRuntime(872): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(872): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.apps.maps/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1536)
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1510)
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2858)
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2964)
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at com.gears42.surelock.ApplicationLauncher.onItemClick(ApplicationLauncher.java:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
E/AndroidRuntime(872):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm using 2.2.1 HTC Wildfire (The same works perfectly on Android 3.1 Samsung Galaxy Tab)

Any suggestions / workarounds ??

Comment: tried cleaning ur project? this often happens with eclipse

Comment: thanks for the tip. Clean Project did not help.
How can I find out how existing Home Screens (eg HTC Sense) has fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Intent intend  = new Intend(new ComponentName(packakeName, className));` instead

Answer (score 0):

this part looks strange:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(872): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.apps.maps/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Have you tried adding that to your manifest?

Comment: this is the activity of some other application which i'm trying to launch (in my case it is com.android.camera.Camera) i need not mention such classes in my manifest!!